# Codeigniter: How can I check if a library method exists without loading the library?

Tags: codeigniter, routes, libraries

I want to separate certain functions from controller methods into libraries to make them modular. Based on the URI I'm trying to route to a library method if it exists. But I'd have to load the library to check for the method with the php **method_exists** function. The only other way I've found to check for it is to put all the library methods in a config array and check for the method name there. Such as:

```
<?php
/**
 * Application_config.php
 */

$config['extensions'] = array(
 'News' => array(
  'library' => 'articles_library',
  'methods' => array(
   'articles',
   'article',
   'edit_article',
   'add_article',
   'delete_article'
  )
 )
);
```

and

```
<?php
/**
 * admin_controller.php
 *
 * all admin routes go to index
 */
class C3_base_controller extends Controller {
 public function index() {
  $lib_chk = 0;
  $ext = $this->config->item('extensions');
  foreach($ext as $item) {
   foreach ($item['methods'] as $meth) {
    if ($this->uri->segment(2) == $meth) {
     $lib = $item['library'];
     echo $this->$lib->$meth();
     $lib_chk = 1;
    }
   }
  }
  if ($lib_chk == 0) {
   // rest of controller...
  }
 }
}
```

**Is there a better way to check for the existence of a library method in each library without loading the libraries?** Having to duplicate every method in the application config is just asking for it.

Comment: Have you considered naming all your crud methods using a standard naming convention? Instead of add_article you would use add. This way all your modules would have a common name for the same functions and you would not have to have an individual array for each module.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this. Convention over configuration. This way I could just check for one of those words, and route it based on the library name param. Such as **webapp.com/library_name/add**

Comment: Exactly. This is how I have implemented my own cms. All my controllers have a common interface that use this convention. They all have at least an index, create, update and delete method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
method_exists
```

For example, if you are checking for the database object if it's exists

```
if(method_exists($this->CI->db, 'set')){
// code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you pursuing modularity for reusable code or are you creating an application that has features that may or may not be present...as in plugins?

It's hard for me to imagine your base application having hard-coaded url's that lead to a library that may not exist. Can you test for the library rather than the method?  That may be simpler to check a directory and load file names into an array, then see if the library required by a url or uri is in that array.

But if you need to stick to your array of existing method names, could you just regex for the method names by that occur after "function (space)" and followed by parenthesis?

Comment: are you creating an application that has features that may or may not be present...as in plugins?

Yes. I'm trying to create an application with it's own plugins.

I was thinking opening each library and scraping the function names would take even more time than just loading the library. I like the idea for testing for the library rather than the method, though.

Comment: I agree about the scraping point...and I like Cadmus's suggestion too.